# Too many arguments for public open fun isEnabled()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, isenabled

I want to disable the editText once timer is finished.
Have a look on the following code:

```
val CountDownTimer=object: CountDownTimer(10000,1000){
    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        txtTimer.setText(""+millisUntilFinished/1000)
    }
    override fun onFinish() {
        Toast.makeText(this@Play_Area,"time up!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        etResponse.isEnabled(false)
    }
}
```

Here etResponse is `EditText` and when i make `#isEnables(false)` it is showing following error:

Too many arguments for public open fun `isEnabled()`: Boolean defined in android.widget.EditText

Please Help How to resolve it

Comment: `isEnabled()` does not take any arguments, the return value just indicates if the element is enabled or not... Your invoke `etResponse.isEnabled(false)` is therefore invalid. Maybe, there's an attribute you can set, like `etResponse.enabled = false` or similar.

Comment: It should be `etResponse.isEnabled = false` or maybe `etResponse.enabled = false`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong function.

`editText.isEnabled()` is used to return the enabled state only and it doesn't take an argument so you can call it like that

```kotlin
val state: Boolean = editText.isEnabled()
```

instead, you should use `editText.isEnabled = true` because the property is mutable

```kotlin
editText.isEnabled = false
```